# Standalone Javascript Typeahead Library

Tags: library, javascript

I'm looking for a typeahead library (providing live input suggestions based on partial input) that does not have any dependencies.

The library should be similar to Twitter's Typeahead library but not be dependent on libraries like jQuery, Angular.js, or Bootstrap.

Is anyone aware of any such library or should I resort to a manual implementation?

Thusfar I am aware of only http://complete-ly.appspot.com/, which is interesting but much less visually apealing when compared to e.g. Twitter's Typeahead library (which has an unfortunate dependency on jQuery).

The reason I need to avoid these dependencies is that the typeahead functionality will be used in a library that should be small such that others can include it without being forced to use an opinionated library.